# Do all arducam need the "Arducam-F Shield"?

Tags: arduino-uno, shields

*The information on this is so greatly lacking to the extent that no related youtube videos could be found, no internet material and the seller seems to be very important and not answer to my questions as he is supposed to.
Also he appears to be the only seller to offer such a variety of arduino cameras.*

---

I want to choose colored arduino camera for my project, but I am unable to receive enough information so that I can choose the appropriate arduino camera.

The most important for me to know is does all arduino cameras need the arducam-f shield board in order to work properly (i.e be programmable, colored, with "decent" quality and be able to capture photos in less than 1~2 seconds)

---

1. This is "5MP Mega pixel OV5642 Sensor Camera Module w CS mount Lens" It costs US $29.99. The description doesn't mention the need of any other 3rd party hadware in order to work.

[image]

2. This bellow is "Arducam-F Shield V2 Camera module shield /w OV2640 for Arduino UNO MEGA2560 DUE" it costs US $29.99 and is a camera that evidently comes with this magical shield. We can see that the version is slightly older than that on the other cameras.

[image]

3. This is "2 Mega pixel Camera Module MT9D111 JPEG Out + HQ lens" for US $21.99 and also, like in any other description, the need of shields is not mentioned

[image]

4. And this is "2Megapixel MT9D111 Auto Focus lens camera flex module with Adpater board" that has autofocus, is 2MP like the one above, comes with .... ?Adapter board"? (nothing like that is shown in the pictures or described in the description) and costs only US $9.99. It looks ugly compared to other cameras.

[image]

---

These was the 4 example arduino cameras I would choose from and do all of them need arduino shields in order to do what a camera should do?
(Explaining differences, pros and cons will be very useful to everyone who are in the same boat as I am)

Comment: @CodeGorilla Any references/tutorials/examples or items I can buy?
I can surely not learn how to operate with it out of nowhere, I need to start from somewhere. Also how come only lo res images? Only with shields I can do hi res images?

Comment: @CodeGorilla Also do you imply that I should choose to buy the arducam-f shield module with its humble camera? Since buying the camera for 10$ won't give me good quality, resolution and speed and I would probably need to spend more money, time and efforts to get it work fine.

Comment: The only way to get high Res, good quality, and speed all together is to not use an Arduino with a camera.

Comment: @CodeGorilla So with the Arducam-shield I can not make photos every 2 seconds, that will be enough for proving the intruder's identity? (I thought the shield has its own processor and memory)

Comment: P.S I also thought arduino uno has 2KB of RAM and 16MHz processor.

Comment: @Edenia - I think it would be best if you experimented to see if the hardware works as you want it too.  I'm sorry that I am unable to explain the reasons why I believe you have chosen the wrong solution, again.

Comment: For a project I'm doing I added 128 KB SRAM, however, you have to 'manually'  program it (meaning you cannot use easy variables as heap/stack). But for a 1024x768x16 bit pic you need 1,5 MB (uncompressed). You probably can get bigger (S)RAM but that cost either more and uses many more pins, which the Arduino has not that many. And of course there is the speed of 'just 16 MHz' .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three requirements:

- Good quality (colour)
- High resolution
- Fast operation

Those three requirements together mean you cannot use a normal Arduino.

1. The Arduino has nether the memory nor processing power to directly communicate with a camera module.
2. The ones you can communicate with have internal buffer memory and use a slow UART interface to transfer a frame. That is not fast.
3. The Arduino cannot deal with a large picture regardless of speed. All you can do is pass the image through to somewhere else for processing. Slowly.

So you can either have very low resolution or slow speed.

So use a Raspberry Pi or something similar which is more capable of using a camera (indeed, the Pi has a dedicated camera connection).

Comment: What about the variant with the arducam-f shield?

Comment: It doesn't magically make your Arduino more powerful. It's just convenience, but still slow/low resolution.

Comment: The "F" version contains a FIFO. You trigger a snapshot and the image is saved in the FIFO. You then download it (slowly) through the Arduino to somewhere else (SD card, etc). You can't process it in any way.

Comment: Let's say I don't want to process the photo, but to send it via gps module

Comment: How do you send through GPS...?

Comment: GPRS* The shield provides GPRS connectivity.

Comment: Then you don't care about speed that much anyway a nice the GPRS will slow you down. I do that very same thing in a project. Takes about 20 seconds to send a frame.

Comment: I will dig info about TTL Serial Camera.. see if it can make photos fast enough.
From what I saw it is possible to have camera make JPEG photos and save them to memory stick for 1 second with acceptable quality and not so good resolution.

Comment: Then I will use MMS or hard compression and I will buffer the images. See if I can make them uploaded for 10 seconds or so